# Reusing same 'alias' property for multiple manage properties in Search Schema?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

Is it supported to reuse the same 'alias' property for multiple manage properties in the Search Schema?

**Sample screenshot**

[image]

If the same alias is used for different managed properties, does it mean I can search using this alias and it will return results from both managed properties?

Answer (score 1):

It's supported but it mainly depends the search scope, it's recommended to use different alias to avoid any result conflict

Answer (score 1):

A better solution may be to assign the crawled properties to the custom managed property and then assign that a unique alias.